# SWIFT - POST image Upload

Tags: ios, swift, post, curl, xcode6

I have been spending extensive time to just upload an image to the server (API call) and get the JSON respond.

I have tried this with curl and it works perfect but can't get it working in SWIFT.

Essentially this is what I'm trying to do (but in SWIFT):

```
curl -X POST -F "file=@test.png" http://www.myurl.com:8000/api
```

This is my SWIFT function for performing the exact same Curl action:

```
func sendImagePOST(myimage : UIImage!){
var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myimage)
//I have also tried this version UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myimage, 1.0)

if imageData != nil{
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    var boundary = NSString(format: "---------------------------1940928093901861121640280121")
    var contentType = NSString(format: "multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary)

    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:"http://www.myurl.com:8000/api")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    var body = NSMutableData.alloc()
    body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData(NSString(format:"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"pouria.png\"\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

    body.appendData(NSString(format: "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    //i have also tired  Content-Type:image/jpeg   and   Content-Type:image/png

    body.appendData(imageData)
    body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    request.HTTPBody = body

    var error: NSError?
    var returnData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: &error)
    var returnString = NSString(data: returnData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    println(returnString)
   }
}
```

I keep getting the 400 respond from the server:

```
returnString Optional(<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
)
```

I use "requestb.in" to look at the post calls and the header ofr the Curl POST call and the SWIFT POST call are the same but the body content are different (I used same image for both calls).

Thank you so much for your help and time on this.It is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you get solution?

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I wouldn't even try to carve out any code from scratch to do even the most basic http operations on IOS. I recommend using a library; a pretty reliable can be found here: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking